# MySQL Order BY where values are stored seperated by ":" in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am stuck solving one problematic ORDER BY situation. Maybe someone can help with advice on how to solve this problem OR help me in which way I have to "dig" to resolve this on my own.

I have table "table1" with several columns. In this table I have column "value", which stores values like this (value is separated by ":"):

```
:1::2:
:1::2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::11::12:
:10::11::12:
:11::12:
:2::3:
:2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10:
:2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::11:
```

I want to achieve ORDER to take into account the numerical sequence from 1 to 12. So, in this case correct ORDER for me would be:

```
:1::2:
:2::3:
:2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10:
:2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::11:
:1::2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::11::12:
:10::11::12:
:11::12:
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to store values in that way. You should read abiout normalizing tables

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I wanted to do without it.

Comment: Whats the logic involved in deciding the order? Are we counting the number of integers separated by ::? If so, why are the last two lines in that part? Kindly explain the rules of your sort

Comment: Can you explain why `:2::3:` is between `:1::2:` and `:1::2::3::4::5::6::7::8::9::10::11::12:` ??

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you order is based last section of your data, So you can find your desired order by split the last section and order by it. The following do your desired:

It assumes your data are saved as VARCHAR

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`,'::',-1),':',1) as A FROM `test2` ORDER BY CAST(A AS INT)
```

However, if you want to do same thing as last section (A) for other sections, when the last section of two record is equal, repeat this method and create B, C, etc., to use in `order by`.